# NHibernate thread-safe way of checking if entity exists

Tags: nhibernate

I've been banging my head off what should be a simple issue.   I'm trying to do the following basic operation

1) Check if entity exists by a field other than ID

2) If not, create entity

Problem is this is in a console app that is multi-threaded, so I need to somehow get an entity by a field other than the ID and set the LockMode to Upgrade (or at least I think thats what needs to be done).  From what I see there is no way to do that with ISession.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a unique constraint on the field?

Comment: No, but I agree there should be.

Answer (score 0):

in a single process use a global lockobject

```
lock(existsLocker)
{
    var entity = session.Query<Entity>().Where(...).FirstOrDefault();
    if (entity == null)
    {
       entity = new Entity();
       session.Save(entity);
       session.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work if there were multiple console apps running... That is what I've done until I figure out how to have the nhibernate/database handle this issue.   What might be the most straightforward way around this is a stored procedure that does the check and insert in a single transaction.

Comment: yes sproc is probably the easiest way after Unique Constraint. Another Option is to sync on a value in the db and use optimistic concurrency to see conflicts